# Php script isn't working on localhost but on remote host

Tags: php

I've written a script and it worked until this morning. Script runs perfectly on a remote server but not on a local server(XAMPP).

Code:

```
    <?php>
 require_once ("../functions/query.php");
 if(sessioncheck()==true) {
?>
<HTML>
<head>
  <title>Admin Control Panel</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
 <script src='js/functions.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">LojraMe</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php?lojrat">Lojrat</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?kategorite">Kategorite</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kerko">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<?php
} //this one is line 55
else {
    header("Location:/index.php");
}
?>
```

Look at my code above to the 55th line on my code.It says:

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in E:\xampp2\htdocs\LojraV2\Lojra\admin\menu.php on line 55"
```

Checked if sessions are working but they seem to be okay.

Comment: <?php> in the first line  is that a typo in your upload? because it should be just <?php

Comment: You are the man, i wonder how this simple mistake took 2 hours to check other files that are connected to this one. 
Thanks!

Comment: it's always the simplest bugs that are the hardest to debug. damn. there's a LOT of zen involved in programming with zend. (pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are including the menu.php file, and the error is located within this file. Have you checked the 55th line in menu.php?

Comment: The problem was here:    <?php> 
I guess the remote server allows this kind of mistakes, and local not. Used same code on both servers.

Answer (score 1):

The error is on line 1.

```
<?php>
```

should be

```
<?php
```

You are closing this tag immediately, which won't work.

You should consider using an IDE that shows you coding errors on the fly - copying your code into [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) immediately flagged the issue.